# Is there a shortcut or script to turn off Internet Explorer offline mode?

Tags: internet-explorer

Every time I lose Internet Connection, IE goes into offline mode, which has other side effects on software like Evernote. Is there a quicker way to change it back, other than running IE, and unchecking File->Work offline ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to disable automatic detection of internet connection status.

1. Launch Internet Explorer and click the “Tools” icon in the
   upper-right of the window.
2. Click “Internet Options” to open a dialog
   box in which you can view options to manage your browser settings.
3. Click the “Connections” tab, and then click “LAN Settings.”
4. Un-check
   the “Automatically Detect Settings” box, and then click “OK.”

Comment: sorry, nothing changed after changing LAN settings, IE still went into offline mode, and even though now internet is back, Evernote still refuses to sync until I turn off offline mode in IE